# Getting active PostgreSQL connection's username as variable in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qgis-3, qgis-variable

Is it possible to get login username from a current PostgreSQL layer connection in QGIS?

My goal is to automatically populate new objects in a layer with an editor login username (not @user_account_name or @user_full_name, because they are not related to a postgres connection).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing a custom expression function:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_username(feature, parent, context):
    layer_name = context.variable('layer_name')
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    username = QgsDataSourceUri(layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()).username()
    return username
```

now I can use a custom `get_username()` function in expression from

Comment: That's great, actually, and there was a question a few weeks ago where I suggested using just this same method, though don't know how to write such functions!