# Getting active PostgreSQL connection username when stored through authentication configuration in QGIS 3

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-3, pyqt5

I've been trying to get the username of a PostgreSQL connection in QGIS 3.6, using this Python code

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = layer.dataProvider()
username = QgsDataSourceUri(provider.dataSourceUri()).username()
print (username)
```

like in this question [Getting active PostgreSQL connection's username as variable in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289479/getting-active-postgresql-connections-username-as-variable-in-qgis)

It does give me an empty string and I think it is because the connection uses an authentication configuration, so the username is not available this way. Is there another way ? I found the [QgsAuthManager](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Auth/QgsAuthManager.html) class but as a newbie I really can't figure out what to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution after observing the [QGIS Plugin "Discovery" from Lutraconsulting](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-discovery-plugin).  See [here](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/qgis-discovery-plugin/blob/master/Discovery/dbutils.py).

The code is :

```
def get_postgres_conn_info(selected):
    """ Read PostgreSQL connection details from QSettings stored by QGIS
    """
    settings = QSettings()
    settings.beginGroup(u"/PostgreSQL/connections/" + selected)
    if not settings.contains("database"): # non-existent entry?
        return {}

    conn_info = dict()
    conn_info["host"] = settings.value("host", "", type=str)

    # password and username
    username = ''
    password = ''
    authconf = settings.value('authcfg', '')
    if authconf :
        # password encrypted in AuthManager
        auth_manager = QgsApplication.authManager()
        conf = QgsAuthMethodConfig()
        auth_manager.loadAuthenticationConfig(authconf, conf, True)
        if conf.id():
            username = conf.config('username', '')
            password = conf.config('password', '')
    else:
        # basic (plain-text) settings
        username = settings.value('username', '', type=str)
        password = settings.value('password', '', type=str)
    return username, password

###############

    myname, mypass = get_postgres_conn_info("your_connection_name")
    print(myname)
```

And as one can see they test for the two password storing possibilities and retrieve the login and password from the one that is used, after searching inside the `QSettings`.