# Disable storage of passwords in QGIS

Tags: qgis, storage, password

Is it possible to disable the option of saving passwords for web map services or web feature services in the QGIS data source manager?

[image]

There is a big warning for all users, but not all employees of our company heed this warning. Therefore I would like to disable the option completely.

Is there any possibility for deactivation, for example in the **qgis_global_settings.ini** or in the **QGIS3.ini** or elsewhere ?

Answer (score 5):

Not a off-the-shelf solution, but a hint for a workaround:

You could edit the `startup.py` script to remove connection passwords each time QGIS is launched by a user.

A good starting point could be these questions:

[Getting active PostgreSQL connection's username as variable in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289479/getting-active-postgresql-connections-username-as-variable-in-qgis)

[Getting active PostgreSQL connection username when stored through authentication configuration in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318635/getting-active-postgresql-connection-username-when-stored-through-authentication)

Info about `startup.py`:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but I´m new to PyQGIS and I can't find the right command to read and reset the user data (name, password) of a WMS/WFS service.

Comment: And you want to do that in PyQGIS? Or in "plain" QGIS?

Comment: I would try it with the startup.py file

Comment: That would not really prevent data leakage, the data would still be written to disk and stay there until a user might at some point in the future launch QGIS again with such startup.py.

Comment: @bugmenot123 you are right, the one I proposed is not the perfect solution, especially in a potential hostile environment. A middleground would maybe `chmod`ding the password file to make it only readable by the respective user... still not an easy/complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a button (in a toolbar or here in the code in the messageBar) to create a new WMS connection without this basic tab :

```py
DLG_WMS_CONNECTION = None

def update_browsers():
    """Updates Browser DockWidgets to refresh WMS connections"""
    browsers_names = ["Browser", "Browser2"]
    for browser in browsers_names:
        iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, browser).refresh()


def display_new_connection_dlg():
    global DLG_WMS_CONNECTION
    DLG_WMS_CONNECTION = QgsNewHttpConnection()
    DLG_WMS_CONNECTION.accepted.connect(update_browsers)
    tab_auth = DLG_WMS_CONNECTION.findChild(QTabWidget, "tabAuth")
    # Hide basic auth tab
    tab_auth.setTabVisible(1, False)
    DLG_WMS_CONNECTION.show()


msgbar_auth = iface.messageBar()
pb_auth = QPushButton("Create a new WMS connection")
pb_auth.setMaximumWidth(300)
# Orange, 12 points and bold text
pb_auth.setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; color: #ff6600;}"
)
pb_auth.clicked.connect(display_new_connection_dlg)
msgbar_auth.pushWidget(pb_auth, Qgis.Info, 0)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. Is it possibile to change this in the qgis system files? So that I do not create a new button, but simply remove the option in the existing interface

Comment: It's possible, but you have to compile the whole QGIS modified version to create a specific QGIS without this tab. The dialog is called at different places and don't emit a specific signal we can catch, so the solution I proposed is the easiest and fastest to set up.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I suggest deleting the credentials in the existing *.qgs file.

Here is the python code that does this:

```py
import os  


def delete_properties(qgs_file, properties):
    """
    Only works with *.qgs (not *.qgz - it is a zipped *.qgs)

    :param qgs_file: Path to *.qgs file
    :param properties: Properties to be replaced with empty string => ''
    :return: Return a new *.qgs file without selected properties
    """

    dirname = os.path.dirname(qgs_file)
    name, extention = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(qgs_file))
    new_path = os.path.join(dirname, name + '_NO_CREDENTIALS' + extention)

    with open(qgs_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as input_qgs, \
            open(new_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as output_qgs:

        for line in input_qgs.readlines():
            new_line = line
            for prop in properties:
                if prop in new_line:
                    new_list = []
                    first_part, second_part = new_line.split(f"{prop}='")
                    other_parts = second_part.split(f"'")
                    new_list.append(first_part + f"{prop}='")
                    new_list.extend(other_parts[1:])
                    new_line = "'".join(new_list)

            output_qgs.write(new_line)

    print(f'\nCredentials deleted, file saved:\n{new_path}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qgs_file_ = r"C:\QGIS_project.qgs"
    properties_ = ['password', 'user']
    delete_properties(qgs_file_, properties_)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, but I'm not getting it right, unfortunately. It may be that I'm too stupid, but I'm relatively new to Python programming^^

I have inserted the code in the startup.py and adjusted the paths. Only unfortunately password and user are not removed.

Comment: @joe_gerner No, this code is standalone python script. It is not for `startup.py`. Change `qgs_file_` variable to your QGIS project file path, save the code to text file with `.py` extention and run in the console (cmd.exe in OS Windows): `python C:\script_location.py` or `"C:\Python39\python.exe" "C:\script_location.py"`

Comment: I followed your explanations save the file as python file and start the C:\Python38-32\python.exe and then run the script. But I always get the following error: "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character. >>>>C:\Users\Test\Desktop\delete.py File "<stdin>",line 1 C:\Users\Test\Dekstop\delete.py
If I run the script in the cmd.exe I get no error, but nothing happens

Comment: @joe_gerner This picture may help you understand how to run the script: https://ibb.co/NZfM74t

Comment: @joe_gerner https://stackoverflow.com/q/4621255/2829863